# Encoding to use to convert Bytes array to String and vice-versa

Tags: c#, string, encoding, arrays

I use this code to encrypt a string (basically, this is the example given on the [Rijndael class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx)):

```
public static String AESEncrypt(String str2Encrypt, Byte[] encryptionKey, Byte[] IV)
{
    Byte[] encryptedText;

    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        // Use the provided key and IV
        rijAlg.Key = encryptionKey;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                // Write all data to the stream
                swEncrypt.Write(str2Encrypt);
            }

            encryptedText = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return Encoding.Default.GetString(encryptedText);
}
```

I use `Encoding.Default` to convert a byte array to a string but I'm not sure it's a good solution. My goal is to store encrypted text (such as passwords...) in files. Should I continue with `Encoding.Default` or use `Encoding.UTF8Encoding` or something else?

Can that have negative consequences on the stored values when I try to encrypt and decrypt them if the files are moved onto different OS'?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should *absolutely not* use an [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) to convert arbitrary binary data to text. `Encoding` is for when you've got binary data which genuinely is encoded text - this isn't.

Instead, use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) to encode the binary data as text, then decode using [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jon. Saves me from serious bugs.

Comment: See also [Phil Haack's post expanding on this](http://feeds.haacked.com/~r/haacked/~3/5hyXGYRO0Bo/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx)

Comment: @Jon Skeet,please help me understand your comment "Encoding is for when you've got binary data which genuinely is encoded text".If I have an xml data and i encrypt that into a byte array,is that xml considered as encoded text?

Comment: @RennishJoseph: After encryption, it's not encoded text, no - not in the way that `Encoding` deals with. You'd use `Encoding` to convert the XML text into binary data, then you'd encrypt it to get more binary data. Later, you'd decrypt the binary data (with a result that's still binary data), and use `Encoding` to convert the result back to text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Encoding.Default` is your machine's current ANSI code page and may well be different between multiple machines/locales. If the data was textual data and to make it portable, you would need to use a fixed encoding format, for example UTF8.

However, as your data is NOT textual data, you can not try and use any textual encoding to convert to a string. The best option is to use a hex or Base64 encoding or keep it as a blob/byte array.

Comment: This is clearly *not* textual data - it's the result of performing encryption, so it's arbitrary binary data. Any `Encoding` is inappropriate here.

Comment: Yeah, clarified a bit once i knew the data wasn't text at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to store encrypted information in files, and you have a byte array, you should store it directly - *don't convert it to a string at all.* For example, in C# you can use `File.WriteAllBytes` to write a byte array directly to a file. Remember that files hold bytes, not strings (if you write a string into a file, some kind of `Encoding` will be used to convert it to bytes, even if you are using a technique that doesn't explicitly refer to `Encoding`).

If you actually need the byte array to be stored as a string (for example, because it will be stored in JSON) then the most common technique is to use base64 with `Convert.ToBase64String`, as Jon mentioned.

(In non-encryption applications you might have a `byte[]` that contains a mixture of ASCII and binary data and you want to convert it to a string. In this case base64 works fine but it hides the text - Byte Array In String format is like base64 except that runs of ASCII are preserved - [C# version](https://github.com/qwertie/ecsharp/blob/breaking-changes-2.7/Core/Loyc.Essentials/Utilities/ByteArrayInString.cs) in Loyc.Essentials NuGet package, Java version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712198/22820))

Answer (score -1):

im not 100% sure here but i think that Encoding.Default refers to the system default encoding and yes that can change from system to system..

If i where you i would use UTF8 or some other encoding that does not change from system to system..

for more info about extended ascii look here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: No, using UTF-8 is *not* a good solution - this binary data is *not* UTF-8-encoded text; it's arbitrary binary data.