# Byte array debug

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i want to print debug and see what is contained in this byte.

code is here

```
SoundEffect sound = new SoundEffect(stream.ToArray(), microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the data you could use the BitConverter class.

```
string s = BitConverter.ToString(stream);
```

Comment: how can i make it a json array? so how the 's' will be an array? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706783/put-byte-array-to-json-and-vice-versa can you change it for this case

Comment: Byte from string works like this: `Encoding.GetBytes`