# simple way to convert byte array to JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays

I have a byte array which was converted from a JSONArray. Now how to convert it back to JSONArray. Is there any simple lib to do this. Or do i have to use base64 as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706783/put-byte-array-to-json-and-vice-versa) post says? Here is the code to convert JSONArray to bytearray:

```
JSONArray arr = //some value;
byte[] bArr = arr.toString().getBytes();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are not specifying no `CharSet` on converting the Json array string to bytes. Simply use :

```
   arr = new JSONArray(new String(bArr));
```

Answer (score 7):

The typical way to send binary in json is to base64 encode it.
Java provides different ways to Base64 encode and decode a byte[]. One of these is DatatypeConverter.

Very simply

```
byte[] originalBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String base64Encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(originalBytes);
byte[] base64Decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Encoded);
```

Comment: So you are telling that i can use this to convert JSONArray to byte array and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

```
private JsonArray convertByteArrayToJsonArray(byte[] yourByteArray) throws IOException {
        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(yourByteArray))) {
            zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(zipInputStream)) {
                return reader.readArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your code. It may help future visitors.