# Convert string to byte[] in angular and saving it as pdf

Tags: java, angular, jasper-reports

I am using JasperExportManager to export pdf as byte[] and then convert it to string to be able to add it to the response JSON object.

In the front end in angular I can't convert it back to a byte array to save it again I may be able to save it with lifesaver lib but it won't open the pdf is corrupted

here is my service code:

```
InputStream jrxmlFile =
      myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myjrxml.jrxml");
//       Map params = new HashMap();
  HashMap reportParameters = new HashMap();
  reportParameters.put("Parameter1", goodsIssueCode);

  JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFile);

  JasperPrint report =
      JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, reportParameters, dataSource.getConnection());
  report.addStyle(prepareNormalStyle());
byte[] pdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(report);
// Export pdf file
return getSuccessResponse(pdf.toString());
```

And my front end function:

```
mergeMap(response => {
let b: any = new Blob([response['code']], { type: 'application/pdf' });
FileSaver.saveAs(b, 'mypdf.pdf');
return [];
  })
```

Comment: Don't convert data to string at the first place, sent it over as bytes only. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20706988/3519504

Comment: Show http call function

Comment: thank u but frontend side is so complicated in ur link

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `{ responseType: 'blob' }`

Try like this:

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((resp: any) => {
   ...
});
```